# DateTimeFormat issue when pass the parameter to MS-Sql stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I have a stored procedure, which has a parameter like `@CurrentDate datetime`, when I pass the value `DateTime.Now` from the front end *(C#)* to this stored procedure it is working fine.

But when I change the *Date Format* as `English(India)` in my system/server, that time `DateTime.Now` will return a value like `25-10-2012 PM 05:23:27`. I am passing this value to stored procedure and I'm getting an error message like the following,

```
Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 10
The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
```

Note : I don't want to use `GETDATE()` from Sqlserver, I want to pass the parameter from c#.

How can I solve this?

Comment: What is the problem with using GETDATE()?

Comment: My Sql server is running different machine, which is different location... I need a server date only which is running IIS Server.

Comment: Then the correct way of doing this is to store date using GETUTCDATE() on sql server side. Then in your code, before you display the time to the user (if required), you can convert it to the user's local timezone and display it. You can use TimeZoneInfo class to get locale specific datetime, for your datetime comparisons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this conversion from C#. Hope this helps

```
DateTime.Now.ToString(DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)
```

Comment: yes @Thangamani Palanisamy.... Thank you very much... It's working fine without any convertions & also dont need to change parameter datatype....

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the date format is because you are converting it to a string and then back to a DateTime value. Depending on the culture settings on the specific server this may or may not work. It may also misinterpret the data, e.g. transforming a date from 2013-10-12 to 2013-12-10.

```
DateTime datet = new DateTime(year,month,day);
  startDateParam.Value = datet;
  endDateParam.Value = datet;
```

"note that the server stored datetime with format '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000'"

Answer (score 0):

You will need to convert the value to a valid DateTime using `Convert` function.

For more information : http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx

Comment: Parameter value is `25-10-2012 PM 05:23:27`, so i want to change the parameter datatype from *datetime* to *nvarchar* and then want to convertion.. right?

Answer (score 0):

Storing dates in local timezones can cause headache when you launch internationally.
If you save current date using `GETUTCDATE()` on SQL Server side, you can get the time in user specific timezone as follows:

```
public DateTime GetDateByTimeZoneId(DateTime dateTime, string timeZone)
{
   if (dateTime == null)
   {
        return null;
   }

   dateTime = DateTime.SpecifyKind(dateTime, DateTimeKind.Utc);
   return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(dateTime, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timeZone));
}
```

You can then pass user relevant timezone like `"GMT Standard Time"`